# Edit django wagtail promote tab fields

Tags: python, django, model, wagtail

Hello I would like to ask you concerning editing default **"promote"** tab in **django wagtail cms** **v.2.6.1** . I am doing bilingual website and I would like to put extra tranlation fields **"Page title CZ"** and  "**Search description CZ"** between existing default fields. As you can see on attached image I know how to add extra field in another FieldPanel, but that is not exactly what I need.

code of another FieldPanel:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    template = "blog/blog.html"  
    subpage_types = ['blog.BlogPostPage','blog.PostAdvancedPage']

    menu_order = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    promote_panels = Page.promote_panels + [
       FieldPanel('menu_order'),
   ]
```

**Image of problem description:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to add new fields in between existing Default fields especially in the Promote Tab you inquired about:

home/models.py

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import MultiFieldPanel, FieldPanel

class HomePage(Page):
    page_title_CZ           = models.CharField(
                                    max_length=255, 
                                    blank=True, 
                                    null=True, 
                                    help_text='Page title in language of your choice')
    search_description_CZ   = models.CharField(
                                    max_length=255, 
                                    blank=True, 
                                    null=True, 
                                    help_text='Search Description in language of your choice')

    COMMON_PANELS = (
        FieldPanel('slug'),
        FieldPanel('seo_title'),
        FieldPanel('page_title_CZ'),
        FieldPanel('show_in_menus'),
        FieldPanel('search_description'),
        FieldPanel('search_description_CZ'),

        # add fields in any position you feel you have need for
    )

    promote_panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(COMMON_PANELS, heading="Common page configuration"),
    ]
```

Outcome:
  [image]